# Attempt Error reactstrap Package path ./es/Fade is not exported from package reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, fade, reactstrap

I am coming across Fade export error from reactstrap/es/Fade

> ERROR in ./src/components/WidgetTabThree/index.js 9:0-38 Module not
> found: Error: Package path **./es/Fade** is not exported from package
> C:\Users\Awais\Downloads\Compressed\newsprkreact-10_2\newsprkreact-10\newsprk_react\node_modules\reactstrap
> (see exports field in
> C:\Users\Awais\Downloads\Compressed\newsprkreact-10_2\newsprkreact-10\newsprk_react\node_modules\reactstrap\package.json)

---